# Java if statements without brackets creates unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

Why does this work:

```
if(name.equals("email_stub")) {
    if(emailStub == "")
        emailStub = results.getString("text");
} else if(name.equals("fax")) {
    if(fax == "")
        fax = results.getString("text");
}
```

But without the first tier of brackets, it will not work and instead fail to logically separate the if statements. i.e. it will never go beyond the first if statement and won't work as intended.

```
if(name.equals("email_stub"))
    if(emailStub == "")
        emailStub = results.getString("text");
else if(name.equals("fax"))
    if(fax == "")
        fax = results.getString("text");
```

I thought it weird when I ran into this issue.

Comment: How is the `else` supposed to guess it's related to the first `if` and not the second one ? The compiler doesn't look at indentation.

Comment: Always use curly braces to enclose any and all control blocks, such as if and else blocks, especially as a new programmer. Else you're liable to repeatedly shoot yourself in the foot, as you're doing now.

Comment: I'm far from a new programmer. I also disagree that curly brackets are required on one action line if statements. Just wanted to know what was going on here.

Comment: It's almost like people use braces for a reason other than just decoration.

Comment: If you had used braces fully, you would not have mis-indented the else block in the second block of code. But again, feel free to interpret this as you wish.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Strange. My posts were deleted. I must have upset someone.

Comment: @insidesin: not me, but it means someone flagged your comments and the moderator removed them, and they will do that, even if the sin is only being too chatty. It happens from time to time, no biggie. But again, your comments didn't bother me, as we're both big boys (assuming you're male that is).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels common occurrence on the internet today, give people a sense of power and bias and they'll use it disastrously poorly. Until you actually start paying them they won't escalate beyond anything other than a willed pressure. :

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go as far as to say "disastrously" just yet. It's not like deleting any of our posts is going to have a monumental effect on anything.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels In the context of their one real job 'moderation', it's quite disastrous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this:

```
if(name.equals("email_stub"))
    if(emailStub == "")
        emailStub = results.getString("text");
else if(name.equals("fax"))
    if(fax == "")
        fax = results.getString("text");
```

Is actually this:

```
if(name.equals("email_stub"))
    if(emailStub == "")
        emailStub = results.getString("text");
    else if(name.equals("fax"))
        if(fax == "")
            fax = results.getString("text");
```

Without the curly brackets, the `else` will reference the first `if` before it.

---

And as @Hovercraft commented:

> Avoid `if(emailStub == "")` and instead do `if (emailStub.isEmpty())`
>   or `if ("".equals(emailStub))` since you should never compare Strings
>   with `==` or `!=`. Also consider use of `trim()` here, such as `if (emailStub.trim().isEmpty())`.

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: One plus, **but**, avoid `if(emailStub == "")` and instead do `if (emailStub.isEmpty())` or `if ("".equals(emailStub))` since you should never compare Strings with `==` or `!=`. Also consider use of `trim()` here, such as `if (emailStub.trim().isEmpty())`

Comment: Yes I agree @HovercraftFullOfEels that's one of my 'why isn't this working' tests, left it in there on accident ahaha whoops.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula Without the quotes?